# Why the routing system has been changed in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 7, some part of hook_menu was used for routing and registering paths (That is what  I have read).

I read an article about Drupal 8 and it said that one of the biggest changes in Drupal 8 is its routing system being ported to something called as Symfony HTTP kernel.

Why is this being done?

Comment: That's a lot of questions there - do you have one single, specific question to ask about the new routing system? I fear this will be closed as "too broad" fairly quickly in its current state. I would remove "why is this being done?" as that's not really a useful question for this site

Comment: You can the info about the same here: https://drupal.org/node/1800686

Comment: @Clive: Actually, `why is this being done?` is my primary question.

Comment: Fair enough - I've removed the other 2 questions in that case. Don't be surprised if this still gets closed as 'too broad' or 'primarily opinion based', it's a rather speculative question. In a nutshell, the answer is because Symfony's routing system is proven, and the old `hook_menu()` was a confused mess that defined both routes and menu items in one place (bad for obvious reasons).

Comment: @Clive: I guessed it had something to do with reducing the complexity of `hook_menu`, but it used to work perfectly without any error or such. So is there any other reason? I apologize for being so speculative.

Comment: Things can work perfectly - it doesn't mean they can't be improved upon :) Think of the name: `hook_menu()` should only be for defining _menus_, it shouldn't have any responsibility for the _routes_ that make up the paths behind those menu links. By using Symfony's routing system D8 gets a lot of best-practice stuff for free, while clearing up its own mess in `hook_menu()`. There's a lot of good info on the [answer to this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89906)

Comment: @Clive: Thats true and thanks. A lot of things are clear to me now.

Comment: Actually, `hook_menu` was a performant, coherent solution that got replaced by a confusing mess of YAML files with different syntaxes and event subscribers built upon the unproven Symfony CMF...